# (1/1) FatalThrowableError in ype error: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::send()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am new to laravel and I want to validate the email of each user before the user can login to the application. The registration is fine to my database but I encountered this error:

> Type error: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::send() must be of the type array, string given, called in /home/jayzdevera/Documents/CrudCCTV/cctv-crud/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 221

I want to validate the emails of each user so here is my code:

```
public function store(CreateApplicantRequest $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    $confirmation_code = str_random(30);

    $applicants = $this->applicantRepository->create([
        'name' => $input['name'],
        'email' => $input['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($input['password']),
        'address' => $input['address'],
        'cellphone_no' => $input['cellphone_no'],
        'confirmation_code' => $confirmation_code
    ]);

    Mail::send('email.verify', $confirmation_code, function ($message) {
        $message->to(Input::get('email'), Input::get('name'))
            ->subject('Verify your email address');
    });

    Flash::message('Thanks for signing up! Please check your email.');

    return redirect(url('applicant'));
}

public function confirm($confirmation_code)
{
    if( ! $confirmation_code) {
        throw new InvalidConfirmationCodeException;
    }

    $user = User::whereConfirmationCode($confirmation_code)->first();

    if ( ! $user) {
        throw new InvalidConfirmationCodeException;
    }

    $user->confirmed = 1;
    $user->confirmation_code = null;
    $user->save();

    Flash::message('You have successfully verified your account.');

    return Redirect::url('applicant');
}
```

Comment: Please show your verify.blade.php file

Comment: Since you are using laravel 5.4 it is good practice to use Mailables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
$confirmation_code = str_random(30);

$data = array('confirmation_code'=>$confirmation_code);

Mail::send('email.verify', $data, function($message) {
            $message->to(Input::get('email'), Input::get('name'))
                ->subject('Verify your email address');
        });
```

Hope this work for you !!!

Comment: Thanks! But theres another problem email.verify is not found sorry I am new to laravel :(

Comment: @JayzdeVera : email.verify means please check verify.blade.php in  resource/email/verify.blade.php (path)

Comment: Sorry I misspelled it. Then I got this error Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Applicant\Input' not found sorry for bothering you guys

Comment: @JayzdeVera : Glad to help

Comment: Thanks you so much! But there is still a problem App\Http\Controllers\Applicant\Input not found but I already imported it in my controller.

Comment: @JayzdeVera : Let me check it

Comment: @JayzdeVera Please put use Input; on top and try it

Comment: Class 'Input' not found sorry for bothering you :(

Comment: @JayzdeVera 

Please add below  line in config/app.php in 'aliases' array

'Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,

OR 

You can import Input facade directly as required in you r controller instead of use Input;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

Comment: It already work and now I encounter this.
Swift_TransportException
Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. p126sm1424793pfp.28 - gsmtp

heres my env:

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

Comment: @JayzdeVera Please create new question for this

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty obvious from the error that you are passing an string instead of an array, Change the second parameter of the [`send`](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.html#method_send) function to be an array

```
Mail::send('email.verify', compact('confirmation_code'), function($message) {
    $message->to(Input::get('email'), Input::get('name'))
            ->subject('Verify your email address');
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But it sais email.verify is not found

Comment: Is that the name of your blade file?

Comment: Sorry I misspelled it. But I ended up with this.
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Applicant\Input' not found
Sorry for bothering

Comment: Maybe the class isn't imported in your controller. Maybe you need to add `use App\Http\Controllers\Applicant\Input` in your controller

Comment: Maybe you need to open up a different question regarding the same with relevant details. Please try `composer dump-autoload` and if the issue still persists please log a new question

Comment: Okay btw Thanks for helping!